# Difference between speak the truth and speak to the truth

Tags: meaning, difference

> “The story in Genesis about Adam and Eve eating forbidden fruit is
>   worth years of meditation. Somehow, eating the wrong things brings a
>   curse on life. The story has far-reaching and sublime theological
>   implications, but may also **speak to the simple truth** that we can be
>   nourished or poisoned with whatever we take into ourselves- the books
>   we read, the people we associate with, the religion we follow, or the
>   food we eat.”
>
> From "The Re-Enchantment of Everyday Life" by Thomas Moore

Speak to something(Oxford Learner's Dictionaries):

1. ​to discuss or comment on a topic, problem or situation
2. to be evidence that something exists or is true

What is the difference between "speak the truth" and "speak to the truth"? Why is "speak to the simple truth" used here instead of "speak the simple truth "?

I have asked the same question here ( https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/speak-to-the-truth.3583343/#post-18231703), but didn't get a valid answer. I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided definition of *speak to* (and the answer given at the WordReference link) describes that meaning well: it's speaking *about* the truth.

In contrast, to *speak the truth* just means to say something that *is* true.

---

- "Two plus two is four." 
  I am *speaking the truth*.
- "People say that two plus two is four. They say this because . . ."  
  I am *speaking **to** the truth*.

Comment: "Speak to" meaning "speak about" is a mainly American usage.

Comment: I reckon *to **speak to** [something relevant and/or demonstrated]* is mainly a *very recent* US usage. Politicians and pundits have been using it everywhere for the past 5-10 years, but I still find it a bit odd - particularly with a referent such as ***the truth***.